# Dimension with different business key for the same entity

Tags: database-design, ssas, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

We have a Dimensional modeling scenario as shown below.

How to create a product dimension if products are from disparate sources and different business key for **same** product.Any Data warehousng expert please share your ideas

Comment: Look into master data management. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190163.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will either need a mapping table that maps the different codes together or some other kind of logic that allows you to combine them (e.g. based on common UPC codes or some fuzzy logic based on names). Your ETL process should then be capable of conforming those product codes to a single product. If you need human intervention to create or review the product mapping then that's probably best accomplished in a Master Data Management environment which becomes a data source for your Warehouse.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestion.Let me know why did some body marked a negative for this question?